# Photo printing from mac

Tags: photos.app

What is the best way to print photos from Mac and pick them up manually in a local shop? In iPhoto, only option seems to be to have the pics shipped. Is there any plugin that would allow pick from local shops like Walgreens, Kodak connect, etc.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/drag-drop-photo-prints/id784329763?mt=12

You can use the app to print to your local Walgreens and pick up there.

Comment: This looks good too. I was expecting there would be an iPhoto plugin